# How to show all users on MacBook login when it seems be locked to boot into one user profile?

Tags: user-accounts, macbook-pro, macos-catalina, login-screen

I have a MacBook - company imaged to Catalina (light company stuff on it) but I shared with another user - and he enabled quick start for just him

He left the company and I want to see my user profile with the machine but all I see is his profile. How do I get my profile to show up at login screen?

Answer (score -1):

If you're an admin, System Prefs > Users & Groups > Login Options.
Unlock the panel with the padlock icon, bottom left.

[image]

Once you've disabled or changed the default login, then you can deal with whether or not to keep the old user's account.

Comment: I can't get past the login page with that other user profile is the only profile that shows up but I know my profile is there someplace.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant it auto-logged. I've never seen a situation where all the users didn't show at the login screen. As you see from the picture above, the choices are auto, list of users, or type your own name.